# Part of Control Ghosts After Close

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering

I'm not sure how to explain this but occasionally I will experience an issue where I popup a dialog (say a file browser), and after it is closed, part of the dialog remains visible on top of my app. Sometimes if I minimize and restore it will go away.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors?

Comment: Yes, actually there are two monitors I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever seen this where the window that you are over stops responding and cannot update the area which has been revealed. However as soon as it does respond again then it redraws.

Maybe you could repeat this test and not minimize the window behind?